# Como mostrar los datos de mi base en una grafica chartjs dinamicamente, conforme se va llenando mi base de datos?

Tags: php, chart.js

estoy realizando un código donde almaceno datos en tiempo real a una base de datos en MySQL, y los muestro en unas graficas a través de una grafica de Charts.js, pero cada vez que quero ver como se modifica la grafica tengo que actualizar la pagina web, y lo que yo necesito es que automáticamente se vaya actualizando al ingresar los valores a la base de datos.
un detalle que tengo es que cuándo ya llevan muchos datos almacenados y actualizo la pagina web se tarda bastante en volver a cargar las graficas, por eso me gastaría que se muestreara en tiempo real.
mi script es el siguiente.

```
**var ctx= document.getElementById('myChart').getContext("2d");
    /////Creacion de un grafico/////////////
    var myChart= new Chart(ctx,{
        type: "line",
        data:{
            //labels:['col1','col2','col3'],
            datasets:[{
                    label: 'ANI INSTANTANÉO',
                    //data:[10,9,15],
                    backgroundColor: ['#ffff00'],
                    borderColor: ['#ffff00'],
                    //borderColor: none,
                    borderWidth:1,
                    tension: 0.7,
                    pointRadius: .1,
                    pointHoverRadius: 5,
                    pointHitRadius: 30,
                    pointBorderWidth: 2,      
            },
            {   label: 'ANI MEDIO',
                backgroundColor: ['#ff8000'],
                    borderColor: ['#ff8000'],
                    borderWidth:1,
                    tension: 0.7,
                    pointRadius: .1,
                    pointHoverRadius: 5,
                    pointHitRadius: 30,
                    pointBorderWidth: 2,
        }]
        },
        options:{
            scales:{
                
                y: {
                suggestedMin: 0,
                suggestedMax: 100
            }
            }
        }
    })
    ////////Fin de grafico /////////
    var ctx= document.getElementById('energia').getContext("2d");
    var energia= new Chart(ctx,{
        type: "line",
        data:{
            //labels:['col1','col2','col3'],
            datasets:[{
                    label: 'ENERGIA',
                    //data:[10,9,15],
                    backgroundColor: ['#30FF24'],
                    borderColor: ['#30FF24'],
                    //borderColor: none,
                    borderWidth:1,
                    tension: 0.7,
                    pointRadius: .1,
                    pointHoverRadius: 5,
                    pointHitRadius: 30,
                    pointBorderWidth: 2,      
            }]
        },
        options:{
            scales:{
                
                y: {
                suggestedMin: 0,
                suggestedMax: 3
            }
            }
        }
    })
   
    let url = 'http://localhost/somnus/apirest/DBAni_lectura.php'
        fetch(url)
            .then( response => response.json() )
            .then( datos => mostrar(datos) )
            .catch( error => console.log(error) )
        const mostrar = (ani_datos) =>{
            ani_datos.forEach(element => {
                myChart.data['labels'].push(element.hora)
                myChart.data['datasets'][0].data.push(element.ani_inst)
                myChart.data['datasets'][1].data.push(element.ani_med)
                myChart.update()
                energia.data['labels'].push(element.hora)
                energia.data['datasets'][0].data.push(element.energia)
                energia.update()
            });
            console.log(myChart.data)
            //console.log(myChart2.data)
        }**
```

y muestro como queda la vista desde mi pagina web.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]